# This Angular.js UI.Bootstrap error seems to not make sense

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm getting the following error. The browser thinks it is handled, but it still shows in the console. It doesn't seem to be impacting anything, except that I would like to have no errors in my console when I push this to live.

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference
at createParser (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:751:19)
at parse (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:785:7) 
at parseDate (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:1478:11) 
at ngModel.$render (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:1517:9) 
at ngModelWatch (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-scenario.js:27134:9)    
at Scope.prototype.$digest (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-scenario.js:22035:21)    
at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-scenario.js:22308:13)    
at done (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-scenario.js:17996:34)    
at completeRequest (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-scenario.js:18204:7)    
at xhr.onreadystatechange (http://domain:50022/Scripts/angular-scenario.js:18143:11)
```

The first thing I noticed is that none of this is my code. It all seems to be either Angular.js, or UI.Boostrap.js code.

I'm using the tab directive, and the date picker. but thats it.

[Edit] At the moment, I am only have this on pages using the date picker.

[Edit 2] Here is my only custom code, everything else is using the directives in the HTML.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var appid = 'app';

    var app = angular.module(appid, [
        'ngAnimate',        // animations
        'ngRoute',          // routing
        'ngResource',       // Rest Call
        'ui.bootstrap',     // Twitter Bootstrap Support
        'textAngular',      // Rich text editor
        'RecursionHelper',  // Recursion assistant.
        'UIDragDrop',       // Drag and Drop handlers.
    ]);
})();
```

Most of these are being implemented after I fix this issue.

[Edit] I am trying to rebuild this in another file to put up to plunker. Once I do, I'll link to it.

Comment: Looks to me like an unhandled null value within the library itself. On your date picker objects, what is your `ng-model` attribute initialized as? If it's null you should default it to an empty string and see if that works.

Comment: "split" is a method from an String object, what is happening is that the code is trying to get this property from a non-string object...

Comment: i think you've passed some wrong parameter to a function.

Comment: I think it will be very, very hard to diagnose without a minimal reproduce scenario using plunker or similar.

Comment: @Mike, Good thought, but the variable has a valid date in it. When I looked at the file location and line, it is having some sort of formatting failure based on a region setting that I'm not using. The setting is not required by their documentation. And I don't see it trying to load region in the network profile, or in their sample code.

Comment: @Rodrigo Fonseca, yes it is a string object function. But I'm not calling it. Everything is in the UI.Bootstrap native libraries. I have made no change. I don't even have anything more than an HTML page with tabs directive, and date time picker

Comment: @Rodrigo Fonseca, nothing in the call stack indicates that this is my code causing the problem, which is why I am dumbfounded. To add to my dumbfounded-ness, the directives seem to be working fine, they are just throwing the exception because they "feel like it".

Comment: I'm closing this out, not because I found an answer, but because I am been replacing more and more of the UI.Bootstrap with my own code, and these types of problems have been going away.

Comment: I have the same error.
It's already bug-fixed, look here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2159
Just update the version of the lib.